# How do I select a button within an angular js element using Selenium webdriver that is only visible when user scrolls or hovers

Tags: angularjs, selenium, webdriver

[The button is displayed in image when hovering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXwyA.png)

[The button is not displayed when not hovering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Enz.png)

[Button displayed when hovering over span element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGSHL.png)

Comment: Which language are you using

Comment: try actions' moveToElement... then a certain amount of sleep for the DOM to be populated (or the elements to be switched to visible).  Then use findElement.

Comment: could you proved a mockup/test harness that replicates your code/situation and post here perhaps?

Comment: button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[normalize-space(innertext())="IVR_ONL_Pymnts_Disconnected_Only"]')))
    hover = actions.move_to_element(button)
    hover.perform()

Comment: Trying to hover on some element that would trigger the span element to allow the refresh button to appear, but it seems the text is not "keyboard-focusable so it is not picking it up.

Comment: @pcalkins This is what I tried.  button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[normalize-space(innertext())="IVR_ONL_Pymnts_Disconnected_Only"]'))) hover = actions.move_to_element(button) hover.perform()

Comment: @pcalkins    I am wondering if I should use the parentElement or the ownerElement which is span.col.col-name.ng-star-inserted but when I hover over the element that I need to appear, I see the span change to span.col.col-name.ng-star-inserted.focused.

Comment: yep, seems like you'd need to hover over the span/div whatever, first... seems like "clickable" wouldn't be true when hidden.